# Python testing with Github Actions on Windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell, github, github-actions

I'm trying to test a Python package on Windows using GitHub actions. The following job description is successful on Linux and MacOS but on Windows the final `Test ${{ matrix.os }} binding` section fails.

```yaml
  test:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [windows-latest]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: nightly
          default: true
      - name: Unit tests
        run: cargo test
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.7'
      - name: Test ${{ matrix.os }} binding
        run: |
          python3 -m venv venv3
          venv3\Scripts\Activate.ps1
          python3 -m pip install maturin numpy
          maturin develop
          python3 -m unittest discover tests
```

This is the resulting error log.

```
2020-05-02T11:26:46.8753138Z ##[group]Run actions/setup-python@v1
2020-05-02T11:26:46.8753394Z with:
2020-05-02T11:26:46.8753556Z   python-version: 3.7
2020-05-02T11:26:46.8753701Z   architecture: x64
2020-05-02T11:26:46.8753843Z ##[endgroup]
2020-05-02T11:26:46.9972224Z Successfully setup CPython (3.7.6)
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0429209Z ##[group]Run python3 -m venv venv3
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0429485Z python3 -m venv venv3
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0429617Z venv3\Scripts\Activate.ps1
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0429746Z python3 -m pip install maturin numpy
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0429871Z maturin develop
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0430000Z python3 -m unittest discover tests
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0470479Z shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0470607Z env:
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0470733Z   pythonLocation: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.7.6\x64
2020-05-02T11:26:47.0470858Z ##[endgroup]
2020-05-02T11:26:57.7836092Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
2020-05-02T11:26:57.7855441Z Cleaning up orphan processes
```

It's not clear to me why it's failing.

Comment: Most likely an issue with the action itself. You should try a later version of the action (v2) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Same things with v2 unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 3 executable is usually available with `python3` on Linux and Mac, where the default `python` might the old Python 2. This is not the case on Windows so the solution is just to use `python`.